# How do I make it so that when I move a part to a position with mouse.hit, it doesn't put it halfway inside of the object I clicked on

Tags: lua, roblox

I am trying to make a game in roblox where you can build using some tools but when i use mouse.hit to get where it needs to place the part, it puts it into the wrong spot.

I have tried a lot of things to get this to work, but this is the best working one I tried, but it still doesn't work as I like, it just puts it halfway inside of what my mouse clicked on, and then the script that makes it snap to a grid (3 studs) just puts in inside of the other parts, or it just messes up when snapping it to the grid and puts it in the wrong spot

```
local tool = script.Parent
local blocks = game.ReplicatedStorage.Blocks
local previews = game.ReplicatedStorage.Previews
local mouse = game.Players.LocalPlayer:GetMouse()
local preview = nil
local x, y, z = nil
local eventFinish = false
local event = tool.Unequipped:connect(function()
    eventFinish = true
end)

-- the function that snaps it to the grid
function snap(x, y, z)
    x = math.round(x)
    y = math.round(y)
    z = math.round(z)
    if (x + 1) / 3 == math.round((x + 1) / 3) then
        x = x + 1
    elseif (x - 1) / 3 == math.round((x - 1) / 3) then
        x = x - 1
    end
    if (y + 1) / 3 == math.round((y + 1) / 3) then
        y = y + 1
    elseif (y - 1) / 3 == math.round((y - 1) / 3) then
        y = y - 1
    end
    if (z + 1) / 3 == math.round((z + 1) / 3) then
        z = z + 1
    elseif (z - 1) / 3 == math.round((z - 1) / 3) then
        z = z - 1
    end
    x += 0.5
    y += 1.5
    z += 0.5
    -- returns the snapped position for the script to use
    return Vector3.new(x, y, z)
end

tool.Activated:Connect(function()
    -- prevents it from trying to place over the preview block
    eventFinish = true
    wait(0)
    eventFinish = false
    -- places a new block at the snapped position
    tool.Place:FireServer(blocks.Block, snap(mouse.Hit.X, mouse.Hit.Y, mouse.Hit.Z))
    -- Does the same exact things as the tool.Equipped function
    repeat
        if preview ~= nil then
            preview:Destroy()
        end
        preview = previews.Block:Clone()
        preview.Position = snap(mouse.Hit.X, mouse.Hit.Y, mouse.Hit.Z)
        preview.Parent = game.Workspace
        wait(0)
    until eventFinish == true
    preview:Destroy()
    preview = nil
    eventFinish = false
end)
tool.Equipped:Connect(function()
    -- Repeats until the player clicks or unequips the tool
    repeat
        -- destroys the previous preview part if it exists
        if preview ~= nil then
            preview:Destroy()
        end
        -- Makes a new preview part
        preview = previews.Block:Clone()
        -- Puts the preview part at the snapped position
        preview.Position = snap(mouse.Hit.X, mouse.Hit.Y, mouse.Hit.Z)
        preview.Parent = game.Workspace
        wait(0)
    until eventFinish == true
    -- Destroys the preview part
    preview:Destroy()
    preview = nil
    eventFinish = false
end)
```

This is what happens when I try to build with it (I don't actually build because I got it so the preview shows exactly where it is gonna go):
[Error video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bb_uPjtXhLk8rltZkJBgWB3wW7uYhqzo/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue around a week ago, the way I fixed it was by making the part a model and putting an invisible part sticking out just enough so the origin of the model is on the edge of the face it needs to be placed on.

Not sure if this would work in your scenario but let me know.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).